# How to change color of a variable in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, ide, jetbrains-ide

I just started using JetBrains IDEs and I use the "One Dark theme" in each of them. I've built my own "Color scheme" on top of it but it doesn't work in PyCharm.

I want the variable color to be a kind of red, for instance, but it stays the default even when adjusting Editor -> Color Scheme -> Language default -> Identifier -> Default (that did it in WebStorm and PhpStorm):

[image: See screenshot]

[image: See screenshot (result)]

I've also tried using the "Semantic Highlighting" feature and setting each color the same but interestingly then the variables are a shade of yellow/orange...

Other color scheme settings seem to work fine...

Comment: some IDEs may have separated settings for every language. Maybe you have to search `Language Python` instead of `Language default`